# How many combinations of weights?

Tags: combinatorics, vector-spaces

I have a model where the input is a vector of $n$ weights. 
Each weight is an integer between $0$ and $M$. The weights must sum up to $M$.

$$w=[w_1,\dots,w_n]$$ 
$$w_i\in[0\dots M]$$
$$\sum w_i=M$$

How many different vectors satisfy these characteristics, as function of $n$ and $M$ ? How to find the answer analytically?

Comment: This is a [combination with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem.

Comment: If this is the first time you encounter the very neat stars-and-bars method...  I envy you.  :)